# Moq verify timeout

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I have some production code which runs asynchronously (actually an actor system). The following test checks whether some interface is properly called if a certain event occurs. It currently reads:

```
var restarts = new Mock<ISystemCommandService>();
restarts.Setup(c => c.CommandType()).Returns("RestartCommand");
var subject = CreateSubject(restarts.Object);
subject.Tell(new Event ("TestEventName", "ValueChanged"));
Thread.Sleep(millisecondsTimeout: 300);
restarts.Verify(r => r.CommandAsync(It.Is<string>(s => 
    s.Contains(@"""RestartBackend"":true"))));
```

The test is green and all is well, but I'm unhappy about the Thread.Sleep(300) part. I can't remove it because the actor system needs some time to process the message, but the 300 ms are hardware dependant. It would be great if I could delete the Sleep() and write

```
restarts.Verify(r => r.CommandAsync((It.Is<string>(s => 
        s.Contains(@"""RestartBackend"":true"))),
        TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500));
```

and Verify would wait up to 500 ms before it fails. Or is there another way?

Comment: This [issue](https://github.com/moq/moq4/issues/931) was created for similar requirement and was rejected stating not to bring the dependencies in tests. For now, you can use few of the extensions mentioned mentioned in the discussion to have the code clean with relevant abstraction of waiting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, the answer is https://github.com/sekskant/AsyncVerifyForMoq. This contains an extension method for Mock, which provides an async verify with timeout. I removed the Sleep() and the last line now reads:

```
await restarts.AsyncVerify(r => r.CommandAsync(It.Is<string>(s =>
    s.Contains(@"""RestartBackend"":true"))), 
    Times.Once(), 
    TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));
```

It's actually 100 ms slower than using Sleep() on my development machine, but I don't care, this won't fail even on the slowest hardware. Thanks!